# Get a character referenced by index in a C string

Tags: c

I have a string.

```
char foo[] = "abcdefgh";
```

I would like to write a `for` loop, and one by one print out all of the characters:

```
a
b
c
```

etc.

This is in C.

Comment: Is this homework? Writing the code to iterate over characters of an array is rather trivial to write, relatively speaking.

Comment: I'm trying to learn C from the ground up. Qt and the like make things easy for you. I want to learn the basics (how things like Qt are implemented). I googled a lot for this, and couldn't find it. Thanks

Comment: Qt4 is C++. I know how to do this in C++, but not in C.

Comment: I think, you can do this using Boost or STL or combining both

Comment: the easy way (like shown in Ninefingers's answer) is not the always the true. There are sometimes unicode chars, multibyte char, chinease chars. Using a sole library will help to provide universalism.

Comment: @Honza knowing C is not necessarily a bad thing but Qt is implemented in C++, the same C++ you've been using. C is its predecessor. However, if you're really interested in understanding C, there's plenty of books around that aren't bad at all. Search this site for "list of programming books".

Comment: You can do it in C++ exactly as you would in C, most valid C code is also valid C++ code.  It is just a character array, surely you have used arrays in C++!?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, well, this is a question so I'm going to answer it, but my answer is going to be slightly unusual:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char string[] = "abcdefghi";
    char* s;

    for ( s=&string[0]; *s != '\0'; s++ )
    {
        printf("%c\n", *s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This **is not** the simplest way to achieve the desired outcome; however, it does demonstrate the fundamentals of what a string is in C. I shall leave you to read up on what I've done and why.

Comment: I'm sorry that you think I'm ridiculous. This answer is perfect. I think I finally get strings in C. Thanks!

Comment: @Honza Pokorny: It wasn't ridiculous as much as it was unusual because it's such a fundamental part of the language that it was surprising to see someone not know how strings are handled in C and C++. It's usually one of the first things you learn in C and C++ (and probably just about every other language out there). I suggest you pick up a good C or C++ book (depending on which one you want to learn) and really learn the fundamentals.

Comment: @Honza exactly. My personal thought was you'd seen one too many "give me the codez" style questions and thought you'd make a tongue in cheek question. Yes, get a book as @In Silico says. I've also written this using pointers deliberately to be awkward. There is a simpler solution (not by much) but it doesn't demonstrate a few things I wanted to demonstrate.

Comment: @Honza: No the answer is not "perfect", it is deliberately over complicated; that is clear from the first sentence, and previous comment.

Comment: `s=&string[0]`?! Why?? I've seen enough such nonsense in existing code; don't teach newbies that way.

Comment: @r because I didn't want to give the straight up answer to the question, because the OP will see a better way to do it as soon as he picks up a book. Hopefully this will get him thinking what that line genuinely means. I think I made it clear that it wasn't the usual way to approach things. I personally wouldn't ever use this particular method for printing a string, but I'd have liked to have seen it earlier than I did.

Comment: This is fine as long as string[] is not a constant string.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char foo[] = "abcdefgh"; 
    int len = strlen(foo);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", foo[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this method more useful than using strlen(). Because strings in C terminates with a null byte, we can loop them like this :

```
void loop_str(char *s) {
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0';  i ++) {
        printf("s[%d] -> %c\n", i , s[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char foo[] = "abcdefgh";
   int len = sizeof(foo)/sizeof(char);
   int i = 0;
   for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%c\n", foo[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```